# Replace [[Word]] with a word from another file

Tags: notepad++, find-and-replace

I have a translation file that looks like this:

```
Apple=Apfel
Banana=Banane
Cherry=Kirsche
Train=Zug
```

...500+ more lines like that

now I have a file I need to work on with text. Only certain parts of text needs to be replaced, example:

```
The [[Apple]] was next to the [[Banana]]. Meanwhile the [[Cherry]] was chilling by the [[Train]].
```

Result needs to be

```
The [[Apfel]] was next to the [[Banane]]. Meanwhile the [[Kirsche]] was chilling by the [[Zug]].
```

There are way too many incident to copy/paste manually. What is an easy way to search for [[XXX]] and replace from another file as mentioned?

Comment: notepad++ isn't the right tool for this. Use a script or something else

Comment: thanks for your help unfortunately it replaces literally everything that remotely has the word in it. i only need it to replace exactly what is in the reference list, eg [[Apple]] with [[Apfel]] but your script is replacing [[Apple.png]] into [[Apfel.png]] or [[apple pie]] with [[apfel pie]]. It needs to check if only the word that is defined by the other list is between the separators [[Appel]] [[APPEL]] and not anything else :(

Comment: Please note that you have commented your question here and not my answer. You cannot reach me with your message this way.

Comment: See my answer updated by EDIT.

Comment: It seems to me you have a second account @Emjay. Please note you need to login as **user1292569** to mark as answered. Later please read https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts

Answer (score 1):

Notepad++ can be used for everything from writing down random notes to advanced text manipulation. But as mentioned in comments you need to install **Python Script** plugin from Plugin Manager.

Copy the file with your substitutions to e.g. *D:/_working/paired-search-replace.txt* and separate values with space or as you did `=`:

```
Apple=Apfel
Banana=Banane
Cherry=Kirsche
Train=Zug
satellite antenna=Satellitenantenne
```

Create a new script.

```python
import re
separators = "=", "\n"

def custom_split(sepr_list, str_to_split):
    # create regular expression dynamically
    regular_exp = '|'.join(map(re.escape, sepr_list))
    return re.split(regular_exp, str_to_split)

with open('D:/_working/paired-search-replace.txt') as f:
    for l in f:
        s = custom_split(separators, l)
        editor.replace(s[0], s[1])
```

Run the new script against the text you need to work on and substitute.

### Edit:

To include the opening and closing square brackets for your special case, the following addition can be made in the script:

```python
with open("D:/_working/paired-search-replace.txt") as f:
    for l in f:
        s = custom_split(separators, l)
        s[0] = "[[" + s[0] + "]]"
        s[1] = "[[" + s[1] + "]]"
        editor.replace(s[0], s[1])
```

---

### For a small translation list only:

If you don't want to use a script as mentioned by others you need to do some special steps using Notepad++. Please note, this is limited by search and replace string length.

Copy the paired translation list to two files e.g. `search-source.txt`and `replace-target.txt` (for working with) and edit the content and format to search and replace strings as shown below.

You can use Notepad++'s RegEx feature and the "Column Editor" mode for this. E.g. select the column you want by holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> and dragging down the column. Then go to **"Edit -> Column Editor"**. Choose the "Number to Insert" button, then choose the starting value and the increment. It will replace the column with the values you want. Use <kbd>STRG</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> later to join the lines

Then try a regular expression replace of

```
(Apple)|(Banana)|(Cherry)|(Train)
```

with

```
(?1Apfel)(?2Banane)(?3Kirsche)(?4Zug)
```

[image]