# Word replacement between symbols

Tags: python, notepad++, find-and-replace

I have a translation file that looks like this:

```
Apple=Apfel
Banana=Banane
Cherry=Kirsche
Train=Zug
```

...500+ more lines like that

now I have a file I need to work on with text. Only certain parts of text needs to be replaced, example:

```
The [[Apple]] was next to the [[Banana]]. Meanwhile the [[Cherry]] was chilling by the [[Train]].
```

Result needs to be

```
The [[Apfel]] was next to the [[Banane]]. Meanwhile the [[Kirsche]] was chilling by the [[Zug]].
```

There are way too many incident to copy/paste manually. What is an easy way to search for [[XXX]] and replace from another file as mentioned? I tested

```
import re
separators = "=", "\n"

def custom_split(sepr_list, str_to_split):
    # create regular expression dynamically
    regular_exp = '|'.join(map(re.escape, sepr_list))
    return re.split(regular_exp, str_to_split)

with open('D:/_working/paired-search-replace.txt') as f:
    for l in f:
        s = custom_split(separators, l)
        editor.replace(s[0], s[1])
```

But it also replaces unwanted stuff e.g. [[File:Apple.png]] with [[File:Apfel.png]] and that's not supposed to happen.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace \[\[Word\]\] with a word from another file](https://superuser.com/questions/1638588/replace-word-with-a-word-from-another-file)

Comment: unfortunately not because it replaces anything that it's not supposed to, e.g. [[Apple pie]] with [[Apfel pie]] and [[file:Apple.png]] with [[file:Apfel.png]]. Also it can't comment there because it tells me to have 50 points.

Comment: Use: `regular_exp = '[[(' + regular_exp + ')]]'`

Comment: I then get `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'regular_exp' referenced before assignment
`, can you show how it would look in the script I posted?

Comment: Escape the `[]`, `regular_exp = r'\[\[(' + regular_exp + r')\]\]'`

Comment: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'regular_exp' referenced before assignment.` yea no matter where I use that.

Comment: Well, add this line **after** the assignment in the original script.

Comment: and where would that be? I tried adding it at the end and it didn't work. I tried adding it over the current regular_exp and it gives me UnboundLocalError. Not everyone is a programmer, where exactly would you put that line in the script I provided?

Comment: Put it **after** `regular_exp = '|'.join(map(re.escape, sepr_list))`

Comment: ``editor.replace(s[0], s[1]) IndexError: list index out of range`` If I do that.

Comment: Please see my updated answer at: https://superuser.com/a/1638695/214658

Comment: thanks! that works a lot better (still minor issues such as it removing round brackets from names but I can manually edit those issues). Thanks a lot for your help and yea sorry but when I posted the question it made only a temporary user that I do not have access to. And can't comment anywhere because it requires 50 points everywhere. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Emjay - your are welcome. But your last comment above is in a wrong place here. It must be a comment to the answer of your first question. Please delete this question here!